# Magento Extensions: How do I tell my build system where the active theme is located?

Tags: magento, themes

My extremely simple build system for Magento needs to deploy some extension frontend code into the appropriate theme folder. But I don't know how to get it to find out which folder to put the files in at build time. Anyone know how to get this data out of Magento?

Comment: All of them .. the code in app/design/frontend/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX and the assets in skin/frontend/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the `base/default` theme (`default/default` prior to version 1.4, or both just to be sure) and it will be available to all themes thanks to inheritance.

Comment: That is not a feasible option.

Answer (score 0):

Each store within Magento can set it's own theme so you might have more than one to consider. Also certain pages like CMS, category or product pages can choose their own theme to override the store and global settings.

To find the *package* and *theme* that corresponds to the folder `app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME` use;

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/package/name', $storeId)
```

and;

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default', $storeId)
```

If calling from a PHP file external to Magento then you'll need to `include 'app/Mage.php';` first. The `$storeId` value can be either an int as used internally or the store code saved in *System > Configuration > Manage Stores* - there is usually at least a "default" value.